# Insert data into junction table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, junction-table

I am trying to insert a set of data into a junction. I want to be able to set the default set of products to every new merchant that is created, then the merchant will have options to set their prices availability etc based on their needs.

I have the current method define

```
def add_products
  @product = Product.all
  @product.each do |product|
    @merchant = MerchantProducts.create!(product_id: product.id, merchant_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

problem I am getting is the below

```
uninitialized constant Merchant::MerchantProducts
```

Comment: try with `def add_products @product = Product.all @product.each do |product| @merchant = ::MerchantProducts.create!(product_id: product.id, merchant_id: self.id) end end` (even though there is no need to assign `@merchant` value here)

Answer (score 0):

Without your model codes, I assume you have a **Has And Belongs To Many** Association. so you cant directly perform any operations on `MerchantProducts` since thats not a **Rails Model**, instead it is a join table between `products` and `merchants` so what you could do is fetch the merchant as per your application logic and assign it to product like and then save the product

```
def add_products
  @product = Product.all
  @product.each do |product|
    @merchant = #logic here to fetch the merchant
    product.merchants << @merchant
    # you will need to save the product in order to create a new record
    # in the join table
  end
end
```

Hope it helps